# How do I sum an amount where the status matches a criteria in MDX and will be context aware when slicing by that description?

Tags: ssas, mdx

I need to sum an amount where a status equals a particular value (eg. 'Paid'). It also needs to be aware when slicing by that dimension.

At the moment I have this: `([Measures].[Amount], [Status].[Description].[Paid])`

But when I slice by Status Description it shows the `Paid` amount for all status descriptions.

It should show 0 for where `Status.Description` = 'Unpaid' ect.

Answer (score 0):

You can slice it with

```
except(Status.Description.children, Status.Description.Paid)
```

and the sum can be determines with a calculated measure like

```
with <sum> as sum(measure.amount)
```

if it doesn't aggregate automatically.